# Can i unlock my SLE4442 smartcard ? Does PUK code exists?

Tags: smartcard, unlock, locked, blocked

Yesterday i locked my SLE4442 card with 3 tried error code using PCSC library, now i want to unlock my card. Is it possible ? Does PUK code exist ?

Comment: I admit, that the question is a bit on the short side, but it can surely be answered.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the [data sheet](http://www.orangetags.com/wp-content/downloads/datasheet/Infineon/DS_sle4432_42_0795.pdf):

> After three successive unsuccessful comparisons the Error Counter blocks
>   any subsequent attempt, and hence any possibility to write and erase.

No, the dumb memory chip has no unblocking command, therefore no PUK is possible.